# How to know if DHT11/DHT22 is working?

Tags: home-automation, dht22

How to know if Temperature and humidity sensor DHT11 is working. I am trying to read data from DHT11, when I read data using Adafruit library it just keeps waiting for data.
When I tried using `https://github.com/szazo/DHT11_Python` it gives me error code 1, which means missing data.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try with my example [DHTXX](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD) code.

Extract the zip to a directory and then compile/link with

`gcc -Wall -pthread -o DHTXXD test_DHTXXD.c DHTXXD.c -lpigpiod_if2`

The start the daemon

`sudo pigpiod`

and run the code

`/DHTXXD -g4 # assuming you are using Broadcom GPIO 4`

pigpio is pre-installed on recent Raspbians, otherwise try `sudo apt-get install pigpio` or see http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/download.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but my code suddenly started to work, dont know why it was not working earlier.

But my question is still not answered because what you have provided is code to receive data as humidity and temperature.

I was hoping there would be some way other than this to check the sensor.

Comment: @ShubhamTayal Check in what sense? It's a digital sensor.  You send a trigger and it sends a series of pulses in response.

Comment: @joan Please let me thank you for that sample code, sir. Better than any other I tried; better than what I did so far; to-the-point frontend code.

Answer (score 0):

And with that, 3 days latter - dead.  More research on the web says that the DTH22 will sometimes hang and the solution is to power cycle.  From a python code I had run across they had used another GPIO pin to power the chip and not pin 1 (3v3).  Original wiring was pins 1, 7, 9.  I've moved the 3v to pin 11 GPIO-17.

Side story: My RasPi controls my hydroponic greenhouse - heating/cooling, watering, feeding a DB (graph of temps etc).  Depending on the temperature the Pi sends an X10 signal to On/Off a 1500W space heater or to run a wet wall and exhaust fan.  So: A) imperative that temperature reading be available at all time - fear of freezing or over heat, and B) I'm anal.

So, once a minute gtemp.php runs.  (among other things) exec("DHTXXD", $th);
then if temp = 32 and humd = 0 (@$!#@ sensor is hung) then:

system("gpio -g mode 17 out");
system("gpio -g write 17 0");
system("gpio -g write 17 1");
rerun DHTXXD
(and send me an txt saying so)